# Don't display the delete button in the index view if only one entry exists

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

`User` has_many `Email` and `Email` is nested within the `User` resource route. Besides a validation I want to make sure that the GUI does not show a `Delete` button for the last email of a given user. So a `User` always has at least one `Email`.

`user#show` renders a `email#index` template of all `emails` of a given user.

How can I make sure that in that `email#index` template the `Delete` button doesn't get rendered if there is only one `Email` listed?

**web/models/user.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.User do
  use MyApp.Web, :model
  use Arc.Ecto.Model

  schema "users" do
    field :last_name, :string
    has_many :emails, MyApp.Email
[...]
```

**web/controllers/user_controller.ex**

```elixir
[...]
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  user = 
    Repo.get!(User, id) 
    |> Repo.preload([:emails])

  conn
  |> assign(:user, user)
  |> render("show.html", changeset: changeset)
end
[...]
```

**web/templates/user/show.html.eex**

```html
  [...]
  <%= render MyApp.EmailView, "index.html", conn: @conn, 
  emails: @user.emails, user: @user %>
  [...]
```

**web/templates/email/index.html.eex**

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
<%= for email <- @emails do %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= email.value %></td>
      <td class="text-right">
        <%= link "Show", to: user_email_path(@conn, :show, @user, email), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
        <%= link "Edit", to: user_email_path(@conn, :edit, @user, email), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
        <%= link "Delete", to: user_email_path(@conn, :delete, @user, email), method: :delete, data: [confirm: "Are you sure?"], class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" %>
      </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Seriously, is there anything you can do yourself? You probably spent more time on writing this question then you would have spent on trying to use if.

Comment: Good morning to you too! Yes, I spent a lot of time to come up with clear examples for these problems and yes it would be faster to use IRC. But someone has to ask the stupid questions so others don't have to. Isn't that the idea of Stackoverflow? I'm thankful for your time and your effort. Others will be too. I'd like to buy you a beer at ElixirConfEu.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right after all, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the `Delete` button in an `if` that checks if there are more than 1 items in `@emails`:

```
<%= if length(@emails) > 1 do %>
  <%= link "Delete", to: user_email_path(@conn, :delete, @user, email), method: :delete, data: [confirm: "Are you sure?"], class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" %>
<% end %>
```

You might want to calculate and store `length(@emails)` outside the `for email <- @emails` as calculating the length of a list takes `O(n)` time in Elixir.

Comment: If calculation the length of a list is not cheap in Elixir: Is there a way to do that with a `count` in the SQL database? Like with the `count` method in Rails ActiveRecord?

Comment: If you're already fetching all the emails, `length` on that list should be faster than the overhead of doing another query for the count in almost all cases. I wouldn't worry about that.